# Node.js GET, POST, DELETE methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, http

I am learning Node.js! And I am confused.

How to create good HTTP request for:

1) **GET** all galleries from gallerySchema;

2) **POST** new gallery inside galleries of gallerySchema;

3) **DELETE** it;

4) **GET** gallery's {path}, like:

```
app.get('/gallery/:path', (req, res) => { 
  let gallery = gallerySchema.galleries.find(g => g.path === req.params.path) // 
  if (!gallery) res.status(404).send('Not found')
  res.send(gallery)
})
```

And...gallerySchema should be in controllers/gallerySchema.js or in modules/...? And then should I require it inside router.js.
Right?

```
const gallerySchema = {
  "galleries": [{
    "gallery": {
      "path": "Animals",
      "name": "Animals",
      "images": [{
          "path": "elephant.jpg",
          "fullpath": "Animals/elephant.jpg",
          "name": "Elephant",
          "modified": "2017-04-19T08:11:00.0+0200"
        },
        {
          "path": "lion.jpg",
          "fullpath": "Animals/lion.jpg",
          "name": "Lion",
          "modified": "2017-04-19T08:11:32.0+0200"
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
}
// GET method
app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
  res.send(gallerySchema.galleries);
});
// POST?
```

With my POST method I got name and path **inside gallerySchema**, not in gallery.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not good practice to store your data in memory the way you are now. Those galleries should be stored in a database for persistence. If the app crashes, you will loose any/all galleries that you have created/modified etc... Assuming that this is just for a proof of concept or for experience/practice, I've posted an answer for how you could handle **POST** requests.

Comment: OK! I won't store data like this IRL! Never :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the body-parser middleware https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Below should help with what you're attempting to do

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post("/gallery", (req, res) => {

    const { gallery } = req.body;

    gallerSchema.galleries.push(gallery);

    return res.sendStatus(201);

});
```

Post the following JSON body

```
{
  "gallery": {
    "gallery2": {
      "path": "Dogs",
      "name": "Dog"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I got null inside gallery schema :(
I used your code and created this POST via Postman:
```

{
 "gallery2" : 
 {
  "path": "Dogs",
  "name": "Dog"
 }
}
```

Comment: I modified the answer to show what the post body should look like based on the implemented code.